# How To Update PDO Mysql Connection to "strict=false"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection-string

I am fairly new to PHP tho I've been programming for years.
I have upgraded MySQL to the newest version and now INSERT is failing over NULL DATE fields.

I am using PDO Connection.
I tried AllowZeroDateTime And ConvertZeroDateTime:

```
 private function connectMysql() {

    try {
        $this->dbObj = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHostName;dbname=$this->dbName;AllowZeroDateTime=True;ConvertZeroDateTime=True;", $this->dbUserName, $this->dbPassword);
        $this->connectionStatus = 1;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->setErrors($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '' for column 'DateUpdated' at row 1

Please assist

Comment: Is the date field NULLable?

Comment: Yes, of course. I should have mentioned

Comment: I found this possibility SET SESSION sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES' but that doesnt work as well

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea to get the obvious out of the way first ;) Next silly question; it is `NULL` you're attempting to insert not a string like `'NULL'` or `''`?